# Interprocess communication with Lua and C#

Tags: c#, lua, interprocess

I have an application in Lua, I want to communicate between the Lua application and a C# program.

I know of several ways to do this in C# (sockets, OS pipes etc) but I can't find any information about these things in Lua (which is a language I'm rather unfamiliar with unfortunately).

The IPC sending and receiving must not block for longer than a few milliseconds, since the Lua script is part of a game and the game will crash if the script takes too long to execute.

Any good links to libraries/tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option I've seen for this would be to use [LuaSocket](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~diego/professional/luasocket/), and communicate via TCP or UDP.

Comment: Aha! A TCP socket would do the job :D

Comment: I'm going to hold off accepting this until I hopefully get a few alternatives to try, and I know just hoe easy or hard LuaSocket is to use :)